# Can we convert Node APIs to Mulesoft?

Tags: node.js, api, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am new to Mulesoft and have a project already developed in Node/ExpressJs, which I want to convert to Mulesoft. So is there a way I can convert my Node APIs to Mulesoft or will I have to redo it for Mulesoft.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I know for sure but I doubt it. Mule is written in Java and of course NodeJS is JavaScript. I would think for something like that to exist, there'd need to be some sort of standard language to export/import an API. I know very little about Node.js though.

One thing I feel confident in saying is that any sort of data transformation that requires extra logic (thus, custom code) would have no way of being translated. As for simple things like HTTP reads/writes, database queries etc.

One option you might consider is running your existing API in the back ground and having Mulesoft call it? That would minimize the amount of work you have to do to get your Mule API functioning in a way similar to your existing API and you'd be able to make any new changes to your API in the Mule portion without having to touch the Node.js portion. Of course, whether or not this is useful to you depends entirely on your situation. It was just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

No. you can't convert your node code to mulesoft. but development in mulesoft is very fast, so you can easily create the same api in mulesoft easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert the code from Node to Muelsoft. You have to redo it. But that should be fast. You have to re-write the code. If you have some java code then that would be easy but in your case, it's JS or Typescript.

If you want to re-use some existing APIs itself then you can call them from Process Layer.